# django unique field

Tags: django, unique, field

is there another REGEX way (or another way) to ensure that a model class field would be unique? (it is not a key, or at least not declared  as a key, is shoulb be a simple CharField)

Thanks

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The normal way to make a single field unique is to use the [`unique`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#unique) argument to the field constructor.

Comment: But why does not it work when I add `unique=True` in `user_id = models.CharField(max_length=20, unique=True)
` ?

Comment: This thread seems to suggest that unique can only be done when a table is created:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17627556/django-unique-true-not-working

I haven't personally tested to see if that is true.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to make this unique on more than one field, have a look at:
[unique-together](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/#unique-together)

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways of doing so.
The first is to mark the entire column as `unique`. For example:
`product_name = models.Charfield(max_length=10, unique=True)`

This method is good when you want your entire column to be inherently unique regardless of the situation. This can be used for `username`, `id`, `key` etc.

However, if the column cannot be inherently unique but it has to be unique in relation to others, you have to use the manual way.

```
from django.core.exceptions import ObjectDoesNotExist

try:
    n = WishList.objects.get(user=sample_user, product=sample_product)
    # already exists
    return False
except ObjectDoesNotExist:
    # does not exist
    wish_list = WishList(user=sample_user, product=sample_product)
    wish_list.save()
    return True
```

Take this as an example. You have a wish list which none of the items can be unique. A single user can have many products and a single product can be in the wish list of many users. However, a single user cannot add one particular product to his or her wish list more than once. And this is where `unique=True` cannot be used and we have to use `try` and `except`