# Django unique=True not working

Tags: python, django

This is from django's documentation:

> Field.unique
>
> If True, this field must be unique throughout the table.
>
> This is enforced at the database level and by model validation.
> If you try to save a model with a duplicate value in a unique field, a django
> .db.IntegrityError will be raised by the model’s save() method.

Here is my models.py

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    # my pk is an auto-incrementing field
    url = models.URLField("URL", unique=True)
    text = models.TextField(max_length=1000)
    # my model is just two fields, one pk (unique), and another unique field, 
    #, the url
```

Here my is manage.py sqlall (I ran syncdb)

```
CREATE TABLE `MyModel_mymodel` (
    `id` integer AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
     `url` varchar(200) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
     `text` varchar(1000) NOT NULL,
```

However, in the manage.py shell, I can freely do this:

```
>>> from MyModel.models import MyModel
>>> MyModel().save() # it works fine!? Not even the text was checked for!
>>> MyModel(url="blah").save() 
>>> MyModel(url="blah").save() # it still works!

# I checked the mysql database afterwards, the models were saved just fine, they
# however did have different PK's (auto incrementing fields).
```

I'm using mysql, django 1.5. Does anyone have an idea what could possible be causing this?

I am using a custom manager, but I doubt that's the issue.

Thanks.

Comment: I got `IntegrityError: column url is not unique` exception for the second `MyModel(url="blah").save()`. Did you paste your code as is?

Comment: `text` field definition has typo.. `modes`. I suspect you did not copy&paste your code as is.

Comment: No I did not, don't think the code needs to be posted as is, only two fields are notable

Answer (score 49, accepted):

**For django 1.9+**
Running `makemigrations` then `migrate` applies the unique constraint to sqlite3

**For django < 1.9**
Since you are using django 1.5, this solution will apply.

If you added the `unique=True` after the table was already created, then even if you do `syncdb` later, the unique condition will not be added to your table.

I can confirm with `sqlite3` that Django 1.5 happily saves duplicate objects with `MyModel(url="blah").save()` if the unique constraint does not exist in the database, which seems to contradict with the docs.

The best solution for you is to create the constraint manually in your database using this command.

```
ALTER TABLE MyModel_mymodel ADD UNIQUE (url);
```

Or if you don't mind, you can recreate your table. (Drop the table and then run `syncdb`.)

Comment: Thank you, it works. I wish django was easier on a lot of this db stuff, like changing & removing FK's, etc.

Comment: With django 1.9.4 the unique condition is added to the table (with sqlite3) - even if the table was already created.

Comment: `Django 1.8` and `mysql` does not create unique entries if you add `unique=True` to your model field after table creation. An overview of the Django Version together with the database regarding unique=working would be helpful?!

Comment: I was confused too. The thing to note is that model validation, which occurs in the admin interface, does not occur during save(). Instead, uniqueness during save is enforced only at the database level.

Answer (score 1):

Running sql scripts directly on the db can be avoided. Rather add the sql execution in your migration:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.db import migrations, connection


def alter_table(apps, schema_editor):
    query ="ALTER TABLE <your table> ADD UNIQUE (unique_col);"
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute(query)
    cursor.close()

class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('app', 'yourlastmigration'),
    ]

    operations = [        
        migrations.RunPython(alter_table),
    ]
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution is pretty simple, Just follow their steps.

```
1 - Dell all the files in the migration folder
2 - Then run the command "python manage.py makemigrations"
3 - Then run the command "python manage.py migrate"
```

**OR**

Do it by the help of a simple SQL-lite Query Adding index Example

`alter table test add index index_name(col1(255),col2(255));`

Adding unique index Example

`alter table test add unique index_name(col1(255),col2(255));`

Comment: If I delete all the fields then how to get my previous data?

Comment: @Shamim your data is in the _sql database or another database not in the migration folder, so ur data is safe.