# Django unique constraint not working

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I want to display error whenever user try to create object with the same name. I want firm name to be unique. [Tried](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17627556/django-unique-true-not-working) but issue remains. Django should display error in the form but why I am getting this.????

```
Firm model:

class Firm(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField(
        verbose_name='firm name',
        max_length=100, unique=True
    )
    address = models.TextField(
        max_length=100
    )
    phone_no_1 = models.CharField(
        max_length=10, null=True, blank=True
    )
    phone_no_2 = models.CharField(
        max_length=10, null=True, blank=True
    )
    reg_no = models.TextField(
        max_length=25, null=True, blank=True
    )
```

But instead I am getting this.

```
Traceback:
File "C:\Users\PrImE\envs\kaizentech\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in get_response
  111.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "C:\Users\PrImE\envs\kaizentech\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py" in view
  69.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\PrImE\envs\kaizentech\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py" in _wrapper
  29.             return bound_func(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\PrImE\envs\kaizentech\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  22.                 return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\PrImE\envs\kaizentech\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py" in bound_func
  25.                 return func.__get__(self, type(self))(*args2, **kwargs2)
File "C:\Users\PrImE\workspace\kaizentech\egirvi\dev\egirvi\girvi\utils.py" in dispatch
  14.         return super(LoginRequiredMixin, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\PrImE\envs\kaizentech\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py" in dispatch
  87.         return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\PrImE\envs\kaizentech\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\edit.py" in post
  207.         return super(BaseCreateView, self).post(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\PrImE\envs\kaizentech\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\edit.py" in post
  173.             return self.form_valid(form)
File "C:\Users\PrImE\workspace\kaizentech\egirvi\dev\egirvi\girvi\views\create_views\create_firm_view.py" in form_valid
  16.         super(CreateFirmView, self).form_valid(form)
File "C:\Users\PrImE\envs\kaizentech\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\edit.py" in form_valid
  149.         self.object = form.save()
File "C:\Users\PrImE\envs\kaizentech\lib\site-packages\django\forms\models.py" in save
  457.                              construct=False)
File "C:\Users\PrImE\envs\kaizentech\lib\site-packages\django\forms\models.py" in save_instance
  103.         instance.save()
File "C:\Users\PrImE\workspace\kaizentech\egirvi\dev\egirvi\girvi\models\firm.py" in save
  29.         return super(Firm, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\PrImE\envs\kaizentech\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py" in save
  590.                        force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)
File "C:\Users\PrImE\envs\kaizentech\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py" in save_base
  618.             updated = self._save_table(raw, cls, force_insert, force_update, using, update_fields)
File "C:\Users\PrImE\envs\kaizentech\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py" in _save_table
  699.             result = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, update_pk, raw)
File "C:\Users\PrImE\envs\kaizentech\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py" in _do_insert
  732.                                using=using, raw=raw)
File "C:\Users\PrImE\envs\kaizentech\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py" in manager_method
  92.                 return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\PrImE\envs\kaizentech\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py" in _insert
  921.         return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(return_id)
File "C:\Users\PrImE\envs\kaizentech\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py" in execute_sql
  920.                 cursor.execute(sql, params)
File "C:\Users\PrImE\envs\kaizentech\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py" in execute
  81.             return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)
File "C:\Users\PrImE\envs\kaizentech\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py" in execute
  65.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
File "C:\Users\PrImE\envs\kaizentech\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py" in __exit__
  94.                 six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
File "C:\Users\PrImE\envs\kaizentech\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py" in execute
  65.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
File "C:\Users\PrImE\envs\kaizentech\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py" in execute
  485.         return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)

Exception Type: IntegrityError at /add_firm/
Exception Value: column name is not unique
```

View:

```
class CreateFirmView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    form_class = CreateFirmForm
    http_method_names = ['get', 'post']
    success_url = reverse_lazy('girvi:find_customer')
    template_name = 'create_templates/create_firm.html'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        from django.shortcuts import HttpResponse
        super(CreateFirmView, self).form_valid(form)
        return HttpResponse(
            '''
            <script>
                window.close();
                window.onunload = refreshParent; function refreshParent() {
                window.opener.location.reload();
                }
            </script>
            '''
        )
```

Form:

```
class CreateFirmForm(forms.ModelForm):
    from girvi.utils import validators
    phone_no_1 = forms.CharField(
        label='Phone No. 1', required=False, validators=[
            validators.get('only_numbers'), validators.get('min_value')(10)
        ],
        widget=forms.TextInput(
            attrs={'placeholder': 'Mobile Number', 'class': 'form-control'}
        )
    )
    phone_no_2 = forms.CharField(
        label='Phone No. 2 ', required=False, validators=[
            validators.get('only_numbers'), validators.get('max_value')(10), validators.get('max_value')(10)
        ],
        widget=forms.TextInput(
            attrs={'placeholder': 'Mobile Number', 'class': 'form-control'}
        )
    )

    class Meta:
        model = Firm
        fields = '__all__'
        widgets = {
            'name': forms.TextInput(
                attrs={'autofocus': 'true', 'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Firm Name'}
             ),
            'address': forms.TextInput(
                attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Address'}
            ),
            'reg_no': forms.TextInput(
                attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Reg No.'}
            )
        }
```

SQL :

```
CREATE TABLE "girvi_firm" ("id" integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "name" varchar(100) NOT NULL UNIQUE, "address" text NOT NULL, "phone_no_1" varchar(10) NULL, "phone_no_2" varchar(10) NULL, "reg_no" text NULL)
```

Comment: I have another model with similar `unique constraint`. And whenever user try to enter duplicate entry `django shows this error Name: Caste with this Name already exists.`. But with Firm model not. What I am doing wrong?????

Comment: Tried recreating db but issue remains. Checked `SQL unique constraint` is applied at the DB level but getting same error. While django should display error on the form it is not. Why??? can someone help me please.

Comment: Updated code. Have a look

Comment: I just removed the `unique constraint` and error is gone. But  why I can't make this field `unique`.????

Comment: Just tried to enter duplicate name for the `name` field and get the expected error `Firm with this Firm name already exists.` But why is it not working with my View. Is something with my code

Comment: Don't know why but. I was trying to enter "Prashant Goel & Bankers" this text. But wasn't working. I had a custom save method which saves all the name in lowercase. I removed it and then tried..it worked.

Answer (score 0):

This error is thrown by database.

But django ModelForm will process unique costraint automatically.

Just don't forget to call `clean()` method of the parent form:

```
from django import forms


class FirmForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Firm

    def clean(self):
        # do some your stuff here
        # don't forget to call super().clean
        return super(FirmForm, self).clean()
```

As it written in [django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/forms/modelforms/#overriding-the-clean-method):

> The ModelForm.clean() method sets a flag that makes the model validation step validate the uniqueness of model fields that are marked as unique, unique_together or unique_for_date|month|year.
>   If you would like to override the clean() method and maintain this validation, you must call the parent class’s clean() method.

Comment: Sorry, forget, that django handle unique constraint automatically. Updated the answer.

Comment: your unique constraint is applied ot database, you are getting database error.  the question is why django failing to auto check the uniqueness, are you in fact calling clean() ?